# R14 & R10 in Heroku deploying Spring MVC application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, heroku, codeship

I am trying to deploy an Spring MVC app through [Codeship](https://www.codeship.io/) CI flow in a 1x dyno on heroku with embedded jetty (version 8).

Codeship flow works but in the deployment step R14 and R10 heroku errors appears.

I have tried in my local with identical java parameters and it is deployed fine in 15-20 seconds.

What could be the reason?

#### PROCFILE

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war
```

#### system.properties

```
java.runtime.version=1.7
```

#### HEROKU LOG

```
2014-09-06T16:12:07.070516+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=17223 -Xmx384m -Xms384m -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -jar target/dependency/jetty-runner.jar target/*.war`
2014-09-06T16:12:07.698033+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS:  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
2014-09-06T16:12:08.350797+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-06 16:12:08.349:INFO:omjr.Runner:Runner
2014-09-06T16:12:08.350934+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-06 16:12:08.350:WARN:omjr.Runner:No tx manager found
2014-09-06T16:12:08.454514+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-06 16:12:08.454:INFO:omjr.Runner:Deploying file:/app/target/MagmaInside221B.war @ /
2014-09-06T16:12:08.477820+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-06 16:12:08.477:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.y.z-SNAPSHOT
2014-09-06T16:12:08.607664+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-06 16:12:08.607:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/app/target/MagmaInside221B.war!/ to /app/target/MagmaInside221B
2014-09-06T16:12:19.847416+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-09-06 16:12:19.847:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
2014-09-06T16:12:23.593483+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.29253714.85382d49-d1fa-4998-86f7-12cea60f83a4 sample#memory_total=319.66MB sample#memory_rss=234.84MB sample#memory_cache=84.83MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=97083pages sample#memory_pgpgout=15249pages
2014-09-06T16:12:44.726949+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.29253714.85382d49-d1fa-4998-86f7-12cea60f83a4 sample#memory_total=557.48MB sample#memory_rss=511.58MB sample#memory_cache=0.33MB sample#memory_swap=45.57MB sample#memory_pgpgin=199724pages sample#memory_pgpgout=68675pages
2014-09-06T16:12:44.727477+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=557M(108.9%)
2014-09-06T16:12:44.727730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-09-06T16:13:05.520637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.29253714.85382d49-d1fa-4998-86f7-12cea60f83a4 sample#load_avg_1m=1.20
2014-09-06T16:13:05.520729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.29253714.85382d49-d1fa-4998-86f7-12cea60f83a4 sample#memory_total=635.76MB sample#memory_rss=511.89MB sample#memory_cache=0.11MB sample#memory_swap=123.77MB sample#memory_pgpgin=250735pages sample#memory_pgpgout=119665pages
2014-09-06T16:13:05.521268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=635M(124.2%)
2014-09-06T16:13:05.521494+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2014-09-06T16:13:07.096312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2014-09-06T16:13:07.096536+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2014-09-06T16:13:07.998339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-09-06T16:13:08.009655+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're exceeding the Heroku memory limit for your configured dyno. This has nothing to do with how you deploy (i.e. this will also happen when you push from your local machine). As for solving this problem, you'd either need to upgrade to a more powerful dyno or reduce the memory footprint of your application.

*Disclaimer, I'm working for Codeship. I talked to Antonio via our in app support tool and we solved the issue, but I wanted to provide a public answer as well.*